# Get a olap4j.OlapConnection from a org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection

Tags: java, jdbc, h2, olap4j

Is there a way to get a `olap4j.OlapConnection` from a `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection`?

Right now I am trying this (as shown [there](http://www.olap4j.org/olap4j_fs.html#Connections) ):

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
Class.forName("mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test;", "sa", "");
OlapWrapper wrapper = (OlapWrapper) conn;
OlapConnection olapConn = wrapper.unwrap(OlapConnection.class);
```

But I get a

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection cannot be cast to org.olap4j.OlapWrapper
>     at myprogram.main(Mondrian2H2Test.java:67)

*:67 is    `OlapWrapper wrapper = (OlapWrapper) conn;`*

**EDIT :**

I also tried this :

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
Class.forName("mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test;", "sa", "");
OlapConnection olapConn = conn.unwrap(OlapConnection.class);
```

With this result :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.unwrap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>     at myprogram.main(Mondrian2H2Test.java:46)

*:46 is `OlapConnection olapConn = conn.unwrap(OlapConnection.class);`*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [MondrianOlap4jDriver javadocs](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/api/mondrian/olap4j/MondrianOlap4jDriver.html) and at the [mailing list](http://lists.pentaho.org/pipermail/mondrian/2009-June/001971.html), the code seems to be:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import org.olap4j.OlapConnection;

Class.forName("mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:mondrian:" + 
    "Jdbc=jdbc:h2:~/test; " +
    "JdbcUser=sa; " +
    "JdbcPassword=; " +
    "Catalog=file:/mondrian/demo/FoodMart.xml; " +
    "JdbcDrivers=org.h2.Driver");
OlapConnection olapConn = conn.unwrap(OlapConnection.class);
```

Comment: That looks right to me. Mondrian can definitely pass on empty passwords.